# SQL mathematical calculations based on text column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 text columns on which I want to do some mathematical calculations.
Table looks like below:

```
Date        Column1    Column2    Column3
-----------------------------------------
2012-08-01  STABLE     NEG        STABLE
2012-08-02  NEG        NEG        STABLE
2012-08-03  STABLE     STABLE     STABLE
```

Want I want to achieve is

- If 2/3 columns is equal to 'STABLE' then it returns 66% i.e. 2/3, as it is in the first row
- If 1/3 columns is equal to 'STABLE' then it returns 33% i.e. 1/3, as it is in the second row
- If 3/3 columns is equal to 'STABLE' then it returns 100% i.e. 3/3, as it is in the third row

I want to know how I can achieve this using SQL? I'm currently working on MSSQL Server 2008 R2.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Does this table have a primary key?  Also, do you care about performance?

Comment: Yes it's date field as primary key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, something like this?

```
select 
   ((case when col1 = 'Stable' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) + 
   (case when col2 = 'Stable' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) + 
   (case when col3 = 'Stable' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)) / 3.0
from yourtable
```

You can do some formatting on the output, but should be very close to what your looking for.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know

Comment: @RThomas make the `/3` a `/3.0` to get the percent. Here's a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/437c2/5)

Comment: Thanks it works now. Was wondering if there is any other way we can achieve this. Just looking at the options available for such queries.

Comment: How about a computed column? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes that's ok. But I'm talking about query wise if there is any other way we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only choices for column values:

```
select ( Len( Column1 ) + Len( Column2 ) + Len( Column3 ) - 9 ) / 3 / 3.0 * 100.0 as 'Percent'
  from Foo
```

The optimizer should handle the constant folding.  They are shown for clarity.

[Divine Comedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Comedy) describes a place for people who write code like this.